# Dynamic loading of modal window in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, web

There is a block with modal windows, in which there are containers that are modal windows.
On the page there are buttons with data-path attribute containing data-target of modal window container.

Example:

```
<button data-target="order-1">Open order-1 Modal</button>

<button data-target="order-2">Open order-2 Modal</button>

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal__container" data-target="order-1">
      content 
    </div>
    <div class="modal__container" data-target="order-2">
      content 
    </div>
</div>
```

By clicking on the button with the corresponding data-path of the modal window data-target, it is opened.

So, it is necessary to load the necessary modal window  if there is a button on the WordPress page with the corresponding data-path attribute

Tried through js to check the entire page for the presence of buttons with data-path attribute and add to the body classes and in wp to perform the necessary operations, if get_body_class() has these classes, but this method does not work because js triggers later than php and in get_body_class() these classes do not appear.

Comment: _"On the page there are buttons with data-path attribute"_ - how exactly did they get there? Are they part individual post content, and if so, how _exactly_ are they implemented?

Comment: @CBroe they're contained in the elementor widgets

Comment: That doesn't clarify too much, but either way ... You will probably have to get the rendered post content, and then search for `data-target="..."` in there. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/ + https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/